# Mobilefirst Invoking Protected Ressource Error 400 INVALID_CLIENT

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

Every time i try to invoke a protected ressource i get this error :

```
"{"errorCode":"invalid_client","errorMsg":"Incorrect JWT format"}"
```

I tried almost all cordova-plgin-mfp versions,

I have the latest IFIX for mobilefirst and updated my mfpdev-cli,

What is wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, this error occurs when there is a mismatch of server and device time. This can not be configured or bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

My server time was 17:38 and my mobile time was 17:36 so  i changed the server time to match exactly the mobile time and it worked,

is this behavior normal ? and is it configurable or can i bypass it ?

Comment: Which version of MFP is being used ? Is the MFP being run in Session Independent mode ? If so Can you Check Token expiration time and if it is too less that this 2 mins  , to confirm if it is causing the issue ?

Comment: The behaviour is expected and normal. The client's time should be same as the server or ahead. Client ( from the past) cannot talk to the server

Comment: It's related to OAuth implementation. Your token contains a payload in JWT format which contains the timestamp